# C - Only one pointer coordinate adds up, the rest is equal to 0

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, vector, coordinates

I have a pointer to an array of ints and I declare initial coordinates values in cells from j+1 to j+3. Iteration of js are just indeces of objects. In cells from j+4 to j+6 I assign the velocity vectors values x,y,z thanks to which, the object should be moved in next steps.

```
int * objects = (int *)malloc(amount_of_objects * 7 * sizeof(int));
if (x_vector != 0 || y_vector != 0 || z_vector != 0) {
for (int j = 0; j < amount_of_objects; ++j) {
    *(objects + (j * 4)) = j;
    *(objects + (j * 4 + 1)) = x_start;
    *(objects + (j * 4 + 2)) = y_start;
    *(objects + (j * 4 + 3)) = z_start;
    *(objects + (j * 4 + 4)) = x_vector;
    *(objects + (j * 4 + 5)) = y_vector;
    *(objects + (j * 4 + 6)) = z_vector;
}`
```

However after I tried to increase the x,y,z coords with arithemtic of pointers only the x value increases - y and z remain equal to 0. What is more interesting the y and z velocity vectors equal 0 somehow as well.

```
for (int k = 0; k < current_amount_of_objects; ++k) {
    *(objects + k * 7 + 1) += *(objects + k * 7 + 4);
    *(objects + k * 7 + 2) += *(objects + k * 7 + 5);
    *(objects + k * 7 + 3) += *(objects + k * 7 + 6);
}`
```

Why does that happen? Am I screwing sth up with the pointers? Any suggestions please?

Comment: You might as well make the code symmetric with `*(objects + (j * 7 + 0))`; even a non-optimizing compiler won't add the zero.

Comment: If you use array notation it will be less confusing. `objects[k*7 + 1] += objects[k*7 + 4];` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 7 ints per "object", but for some reason you are multiplying by 4.

Your code should be:

```
for (int j = 0; j < amount_of_objects; ++j) {
    *(objects + (j * 7)) = j;
    *(objects + (j * 7 + 1)) = x_start;
    ...
```

This code would be much clearer and less error-prone if you made a struct containing the 7 ints, and then worked in terms of those structs.

Comment: Ah yes, thx for pointing that out, that was a part of code I forgot to change after creating a bigger array + it's kinda late here and I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

You are scaling by 4 in the first code block and 7 in the second code block. Assuming you want the layout of the accesses to be the same, you should use the same size. Index with `y*Y_SIZE + x`. I assume you want to multiply by 7 and not 4 because you are writing seven values at a time.

Also, you should probably not hard code the size, to avoid this issue in the future.